# Religions that have disappeared/declined significantly in places where they originated or once flourished?

Tags: christianity, demography, buddhism

I'm interested in a list of religions that have either disappeared or significantly declined in followership in the place where they originated or once flourished. One example that I have is for Buddhism in India (former case), as well as to some degree Christianity in Western Europe (latter case). I'd like some more examples, if there are any (I'm sure there is at least 1 other example) of religions that have exhibited such phenomenon.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Christianity disappeared in Western Europe?

Comment: Are you looking for something like Norse religions were replaced by Christianity as kings (and peoples) converted?

Comment: Isn't there an established policy against asking for lists of examples?

Comment: The ancient Greek religion,Manichaeism, Zoroastrianism, gnosticism etc etc etc

Comment: Voted to close as too broad, fishing for 'a list of ...' , so no single correct answer.

Comment: Might want to clarify if you’re (as I suspect) not looking for religions that just went extinct or nearly, but ones that have been transplanted to new cultural contexts.

Comment: Please check Meta - list questions are problemmatic since there is no way to select one authoritative answer.   Also, the answers tend to generate more debate that enlightenment as these comments demonstrate.  Pagan/animist religions were once universal and are now almost universally replaced.  And how do you draw a distinction between Roman Catholicism, Christianity, Protestantism, Evangelicalism and the various snake handler sects?  The Iranians would insist that Islam began in Mecca, but has been replaced by a heresy. Are Sufi's Islamic?  Regret to VtC unless the terms can be clarified.

Comment: @rougon my question pertains to religions that have either disappeared or significantly declined in terms of followership, either in their place of origin or where they once flourished.

Answer (score 3):

The best example I can provide you with is the Ancient Persian Zoroastrian religion.

Zoroastrianism, was either the earliest or certainly one of the earliest religions of Ancient Persia-(present-day Iran).  The dates for the Founder of Zoroastrianism-(the Prophet Zoroaster or Zarathustra), are debatable, ranging anywhere between 600 BC/BCE-1000 BC/BCE. I personally tend to think that Zoroaster/Zarathustra lived around the 600's BC/BCE-(which was the same time when Persia, as a civilization, was uniting into a major power and preparing for their imperial campaigning across much of Asia).

The Zoroastrian religion was the national religion of Persia-(as well as neighboring Uzbekistan, though to a limited extent) for nearly 1300 years, until the arrival of the Arabs and the Islamic religion.  When the Muslims conquered Persia-(specifically, the Early Medieval Sassanian Empire), the vast majority of its inhabitants were forcibly converted to Islam and a tiny percentage of Zoroastrians remained within Persia. Immediately before the Arab Muslim conquest of Sassanian Persia, a small percentage of Persian Zoroastrians migrated to India and have resided in India to the present-day-(they are referred to as, "Parsis").

Zoroastrianism is barely kept alive within contemporary Iran, though the Parsis of India have retained many of their ancient Zoroastrian practices into the present-day.

Comment: Whoever cast the down vote,  I am curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

The eradication of Christianity in the Middle East comes to mind. In fact, it's history in the making, as it continues to this very day.

I noticed people find my answer incorrect. Probably because it's happening right now. That is not history, is it?

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_in_the_Middle_East#Persecution_of_Christians_in_Middle_East
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Christians_in_the_modern_era#Middle_East
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assyrian_exodus_from_Iraq
- https://www.huffingtonpost.com/alon-benmeir/the-persecution-of-christ_b_13652002.html